# Import symbol from other font without wasting math alphabet

Tags: fonts, symbols

I wish to import a symbol from `newtxmath` for use with `kpfonts` without using up a math alphabet to do it. As seen in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215270/can-someone-explain-this-weird-font-behavior-ebgaramond-maths) it is easy to do so if one is willing to waste a math alphabet, but in their answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font), egreg seems to say that it is possible to avoid this by using the `pifont` package.

For reference, this works but uses up a math alphabet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\newpartial}{\mathord}{ntxletters}{64}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ \partial \newpartial \]
\end{document}
```

Following (as far as I can tell correctly) egreg's instructions would lead me to the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{pifont}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Pimathsymbol[3][\mathord]{%
  #1{\@Pimathsymbol{#2}{#3}}}
\def\@Pimathsymbol#1#2{\mathchoice
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\sf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\ssf@size}}
\def\@Pim@thsymbol#1#2#3{%
  \mbox{\fontsize{#3}{#3}\Pisymbol{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\newpartial}{\Pimathsymbol[\mathord]{ntxmmi}{64}}
\begin{document}
\[ \partial \newpartial \]
\end{document}
```

This compiles but gives the following error messages:

```
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
Font shape `U/ntxmmi/m/n' undefined
(Font)  using `U/jkpexa/m/n' instead.
```

The output is also wrong, substituting a (subscript?) `\oiintctrclockwise` from `kpfonts` instead. I suppose this symbol fills the 64 slot of the `jkpexa` font.

If I understand egreg correctly, this method is not sufficient in the linked question above since the asker wishes to import a symbol from `mathabx`, and this does not provide `.fd` files. But as far as I can tell, `newtxmath` *does* provide (at least some) `.fd` files [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtx/tex).

(Note that I am using pdfLaTeX. Not sure if that is significant enough for it to be a tag.)

Answer (score 9):

That's just for symbols in the “Pi” font.

If you don't need the symbol to respect `\boldmath`, it's as easy as

```
\newcommand{\newpartial}{\mathord{\text{\usefont{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}}}
```

Complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\newcommand{\newpartial}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\newpartial}{%
  \mathord{\text{\usefont{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[ \partial \newpartial \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better using `\DeclareRobustCommand` so if the symbol gets its way in some moving argument you don't get garbage in the `.aux` file.

For `\boldmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\newcommand{\newpartial}{%
  \mathord{\text{\usefont{OML}{ntxmi}{\mediumorbold}{it}\symbol{64}}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mediumorbold}{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\math@version}{bold}=0 b\else m\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \partial \newpartial \]

\boldmath
\[ \partial \newpartial \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see! Thank you. I think I misunderstood the relationship between `pifont`, `newtx` and `mathptm`: From the `PSNFSS` documentation it seemed like it used to support `mathptm`, but that this had been replaced by `newtx`. I guess I thought `pifont` could (still) be used as an interface to `newtx`, but I suppose not. I don't need a bold version for this particular symbol, but suppose I did, would that be significantly more difficult? (I don't want to ask you for a solution if it is, but in case I ever need to import bold symbols in the future it would be nice to know how difficult it would be.)

Comment: @Danny It's not so difficult (it would be to support `\bm`, though).