# Does LaTex support a "Fair Use" symbol?

Tags: logos

Is there a *TeX*/*LaTeX* icon/symbol with the ***FU*** for "Fair Use":

[image]

as appears on [this page](https://www.wikiart.org/en/rene-magritte/the-treachery-of-images-this-is-not-a-pipe-1948)?

I couldn't find it on Creative Commons or elsewhere.

Comment: that is not a font chararacter it is an SVG image https://uploads.wikiart.org/Content/wiki/img/fair-use.svg  You could include it via svg package, or convert it to pdf and use `\includegraphics`

Comment: or png versions from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fair_use_logo.svg

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for .eps, and will keep looking.

Comment: why  eps? In any event it is trivial to turn an svg to eps or pdf, anything that can print svg could do that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  I prefer to have a bona fide .eps character (much like the `\cc` and `\copyright` symbol) as overall font characteristics will generally apply, such as `\bf` or changes in font size and so on.  True... this can be done with an included graphics, but it isn't as elegant.  If there is a direct way to convert the svg to eps *that will allow such font face and size change*, well, I've never learned how to do that.

Comment: You are mistaken. `\bf` will not apply to a EPS, latex/dvips can include eps via `\includegraphics`  pdflatex and lualatex can not use eps at all: you would have to convert the eps to pdf to include it

Comment: \copyright is a character in a font like abc © not an EPS

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  You are correct.  What I should have requested is a *character* (which I *render* in .eps).  Anyway, I trust you can see I was hoping for the equivalent of a `\fairuse`.

Comment: a logo is really a graphic, you wouldn't squash a  twitter bird just because the text is italic. `\newcommand\fairuse{\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{fairuse}` will give such a command that scales with current font. (and is equivlent to the css including the image on the web page you linked to)

Comment: Looking around there's https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643188/250119 which has some discussion on how to make includegraphics "change by font style" (but no definite answer...)

Comment: no not style just size, as I wrote in the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

*Community wiki*

The *fair use* symbol is a graphics and not a font character. Therefore, the symbol can be included using LaTeX graphics commands.

The graphics is available for example here: https://uploads.wikiart.org/Content/wiki/img/fair-use.svg.